RuntimeError: Caught RuntimeError in replica 1 on device 1
I want to apply data parallel on my model, so i want to train the model on 2 GPUs ,
F
irst at the beginning  i set the cuda visible devices:
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0,1"

Then I set the model:
  
    ### MODEL ###
    model = CompleteModel(
        block=Bottleneck2D,
        vote_index=vote_index,
        depth=M.depth,
        num_stacks=M.num_stacks,
        num_blocks=M.num_blocks,
        num_classes=sum(sum(M.head_size, [])),
        head=lambda c_in, c_out: MultitaskHead(c_in, c_out)
    ).to(device).half()
    # Apply DataParallel
    if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:  
        model = nn.DataParallel(model)  

Once I applied data parallel, I got these 2 errors:
RuntimeError: Caught RuntimeError in replica 1 on device 1.
File "/mnt/CODE/TRAIN_Komondor_DataParallel/lcnn/models/complete_model.py", line 189, in forward

.....
 y = self.hg_ht(y)
  File "/opt/mamba/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/CODE/TRAIN_Komondor_DataParallel/lcnn/models/HT.py", line 225, in forward
    y = self.htiht(x)
  File "/opt/mamba/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/CODE/TRAIN_Komondor_DataParallel/lcnn/models/HT.py", line 199, in forward
    out = self.ht(x)
  File "/opt/mamba/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/CODE/TRAIN_Komondor_DataParallel/lcnn/models/HT.py", line 137, in forward
    HT_map = image @ self.vote_index
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:1 and cuda:0! (when checking argument for argument mat2 in method wrapper_mm)

I tried this: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/data_parallel_tutorial.html
Are there any solutions for this errors?
